# Right Shift in java

Tags: java, digital-logic

I am just stuck with this small logic that i am not getting it right

`int` is 32 bits so suppose taking 20 in binary would be like

```
// 00000000000000000000000000010100
```

.. now if I perform rightshift operation say 4

```
int a = 20>>4;   
// 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

..so result is 1

Now say I again take 20 and do 5 right shift operation

```
int b = 20>>5;  //00000000000000000000000000000000
```

..so result is 0

Now if I do 32 right shift ... why I am getting the same number as I assigned.??

```
int c = 20>>32; //how does this prints 20 again??

System.out.println("right shift 4= "+a+"\n right shift 5= "+b+"right shift 32 = "+c);
```

So what I was expecting is after 5 shifts ..any number of shifts should have resulted in the result 0.. but on 32 shifts why I am getting back the assigned value?

Comment: A sane compiler would have warned you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JLS 15.19. Shift Operators

If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive

Answer (score 7):

When you shift an `int` only the lower 5 bits of the shift are used.  When you shift a `long` only the lowest 6 bits are used.

From the [Java Language Specification section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f
>   (0b11111). *The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive*.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the
>   six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f
>   (0b111111). *The shift distance actually used is therefore always in
>   the range 0 to 63, inclusive.*

Comment: While this is true it would be nice to explain it bit more. What this answer is trying to say is that since 32 in bit representation is `100000` last 5 bits are `00000` which represents `0` so there will be no bit shifting. For `long` type no shifting would happen for `64` (`1000000`) and its multiplications.